# What types of ropes are there for multi-purpose camping that are strong?

Tags: gear, camping, ropes

I'm looking for a multi-purpose rope for camping with the following specs:

- Synthetic
- Preferably 7/16" dia or less
- 750-1000lb test break strength

I don't plan on climbing with this rope but it would be nice to know that every time I jump into my hammock I don't surpass the dynamic load rating. Aside from high quality rope for climbing and towing, the only rope I see with ratings is paracord, and I'm just not buying the 750lb test from a shoe string.  I was hoping a reputable rope manufacturer might have more of an economy model.  Does anyone have any suggestions about where I might look?

Comment: [Pelican Ropes](https://www.pelicanrope.com/), a US supplier, has a [rope selection guide](https://www.pelicanrope.com/pdfs/PelicanRope-Catalog-2015.pdf) which gives breaking strain for its products. I have no connection with them. If you use a very thin cord, you can risk cutting into the thing you are securing, or fixing it to, unless using multiple strands. A man-made fibre that is too slippery won't tie secure knots. An natural fibre can shrink when wet and knots hard to untie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Answer

[Sterling Accessory Cord](https://sterlingrope.com/store/climb/cordage/accessory-cords) is probably somewhat ideal for your weight specs while still being a reasonable price. Stronger than what you are looking and from a very reputable brand. I use sterling accessory cord all the time; it is a staple in my whitewater kayaking rescue kit for prussics. They have a bunch of sizes, but here are three in your general strength area.

- 4mm cord is 876lbs break strength
- 5mm cord is 1,169lbs break strength
- 6mm cord is 1,978lbs break strength

## Hammocking

In regards to hammocking, remember that the break strength of the rope and the ability for it to support a hammock are VERY different. When using rope to support a hammock it is at an angle which greatly [reduces load capacity](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/rope-angle-tension-increase-d_1507.html) (45 degrees is a 40% increase in load for example). When setting up for a hammock you are also going to have knots. Knots again will greatly reduce your load capacity (50+% easily). You are also moving up and down when you get in which increases the load on the line. I personally wouldn't hammock on anything rated below 1750lbs (so the 6mm would be fine). All the talk about weight aside, **DON'T HAMMOCK ON PLAIN CORD** because it is bad for the trees. You should be using webbing, or at least put something between the trees and the cord.